# Method vs. Field name in toString() method

Tags: java, tostring

Just when I think I've got the basics of Java down (it's been a full semester!), something happens to make me question that.  I'm doing some practice review and have a bit of a problem.  Here's the code:

```
public class LetterCount 
{
    private char[] wordArray;
    private int numVowels = 0, numConsonants = 0, numSpaces = 0, numDigits = 0;

    public LetterCount(String str)
    {
        wordArray = str.toCharArray();
    }

    public int getNumVowels()
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < wordArray.length; count++)
        {
           if (wordArray[count] == 'a' || wordArray[count] == 'e' || 
               wordArray[count] == 'i' || wordArray[count] == 'o' || wordArray[count] 
               == 'u' || wordArray[count] == 'y')

           numVowels++;
        }
        return numVowels;
    }

    public int getNumDigits()
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < wordArray.length; count++)
        {
            if (Character.isDigit(wordArray[count]))
                numDigits++;
        }
        return numDigits;
    }

    public int getWhiteSpace()
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < wordArray.length; count++)
        {
            if (Character.isSpaceChar(wordArray[count]))
                numSpaces++;
        }

        return numSpaces;
    }

    public int getNumConsonants()
    {       
        numConsonants = wordArray.length - getNumVowels() - getNumDigits() - getWhiteSpace();

        return numConsonants;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "Characters: " + wordArray.length + "\n" +
    "Vowels: " + getNumVowels() + "\n" +
                "Consonants: " + getNumConsonants() + "\n" +
                "Digits: " + getNumDigits() + "\n" +
                "Spaces: " + getWhiteSpace();

        return str;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter a sentence: this is a test 4 u
Characters: 18
Vowels: 5
Consonants: 2
Digits: 2
Spaces: 10
```

My questions: 
1) I was sure I could use field names in the toString() method (e.g., *numVowels* vs. *getNumConsonants()*), but it seems this class requires me to use method names.  When I use field names I get 0. Why the difference?  I do know that if I return an equation, I have to use the method name.

2) I also don't understand why my numConsonants() method doesn't return the correct numbers.  If I return each field separately (and call the method since I can't call the field name), I get the correct number.  Put them in an equation and it's incorrect.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's the original main method.  I've since edited it to call the methods in the LetterCount class:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


public class LetterCountDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String sentence;
        LetterCount lc;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
        sentence = keyboard.nextLine();

        lc = new LetterCount(sentence);

        System.out.println(lc);
    }

}
```

Added:

```
        lc.getNumVowels();
    lc.getNumConsonants();
```

Comment: Woah there, your getters are changing the instance variables. You should calculate them only once (maybe in the constructor) instead.

Comment: Please post the main method you are using to instantiate your class object and also to get your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason you have to use method instead of field is simple. Your methods are not simple accessor  methods.(Check [this link](http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/accessormutator.htm)) They do some calculations and update the filed variables and return them. So until you call the method your fields are having value zero.

This way of updating field variable is bad. If you call the method twice (eg:`getNumVowels`), it will update the already updated field variable `numVowels`.

Problem with `getNumConsonants` is related to above answer.

Solution here would be not to use field variables and use local variable. See below example.

```
public int getNumDigits()
{
    int numDigits = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < wordArray.length; count++)
    {
        if (Character.isDigit(wordArray[count]))
            numDigits++;
    }
    return numDigits;
}
```

With this modification `getNumDigits()` will always return correct answer.

Comment: Ugh, will I ever be ready for primetime?  The problem was in my main method.  You're all correct (of course).  I never actually called the methods so they either sat there or only executed the one time in my toString() method. Perhaps I shouldn't practice all day everyday.  My brain is obviously fried.  Thanks to you all!  I LOVE this forum.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'field' (it's known as a 'member variable'), but in your case, it's initialized to zero, and only updated by the method.

So, if you never call the method, the member variable is never updated, so remains at zero.

Also, you don't 'call field names' - you can call a method, which may return a value.
You can reference that value, and similarly you can reference a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is relatively simple.  The fields are zero until the methods are called at least once.  In other words, the fields are set in the methods so you have to call the methods first.

The answer to the second question is related.  When you call `getNumVowels`, `getNumDigits`, or `getWhitespace` your are increasing the field values.  If you initialize them to zero at the beginning, your approach will work.